# Why autoplay does not start in Edge

Tags: html

I currently have a problem with the MP3 audio, indeed, autoplay does not work when I launch the page and the loop does not work either if I add the controls, and I click on the play button it runs. I do not know if the problem comes from the browser (Edge).

```
<audio autoplay loop>
        <source src="src/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that for video autoplay only works if it is muted. I would assume that it is the same for audio, so you would have to mute it for autoplay to work.

Comment: I just tried but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

how big is your audio file? if you want to use autoplay. the browser will load the full file first and then it will play the audio.
you can check the doc here:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The size of my audio file is 64 kbsp, 1.32MB.

I already went to see the link https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp but it still doesn't work